# base pointer value after leave

Tags: assembly, x86

I checked the register values of the following simple executable file (ELF, X86-64). Can you explain why "rbp" is "0x7ffd222f1e80" after "leave"?

I know "leave" means the following two instructions.

```
mov    %rbp,%rsp
pop    %rbp
```

So I expected this value.

```
mov $1, %eax
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70

leave
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e78   0x7ffd222f1e78
```

// main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f();

int main() {
  return f();
}
```

// func.s

```
.data
    .text
    .global f
f:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    mov $1, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

// compile and debug

```
# gcc -g main.c func.s -o main
# gdb ./main
# b main
# b f
# r
# s
# i all
```

// register

```
main
rax            0x55dced86d5fa   94407366202874
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e80   0x7ffd222f1e80
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e80   0x7ffd222f1e80

f
rax            0x0  0
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e80   0x7ffd222f1e80
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e78   0x7ffd222f1e78

push %rbp
rax            0x0  0
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e80   0x7ffd222f1e80
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70

mov %rsp, %rbp
rax            0x0  0
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70

mov $1, %eax
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e70   0x7ffd222f1e70

leave
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e80   0x7ffd222f1e80 (???)
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e78   0x7ffd222f1e78

ret
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7ffd222f1e80   0x7ffd222f1e80
rsp            0x7ffd222f1e80   0x7ffd222f1e80
```

// stack

```
-----------------
0x7ffd222f1e70
-----------------
0x7ffd222f1e78
-----------------
0x7ffd222f1e80
-----------------
```

Comment: The new value of rbp was popped off the stack (second part of leave instruction).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you. I'm still confused. give me some time to think.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I didn't understand correctly about "call", "pop" and "ret" instruction. Now I think I understand it.

[image]

[image]

Procedures and Call Stacks
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse351/12au/lecture-slides/07-procedures.pdf

1 before calling f():

```
rax            0x55ce8dc245fa   94345629943290
rbp            0x7fff30b035b0   0x7fff30b035b0
rsp            0x7fff30b035b0   0x7fff30b035b0
rip            0x55ce8dc245fe   0x55ce8dc245fe <main+4>

--------------|--------------
ADDRESS       |VALUE
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035b0|               <= rsp, rbp
--------------|--------------
```

2 start calling f():

```
rax            0x0  0
rbp            0x7fff30b035b0   0x7fff30b035b0
rsp            0x7fff30b035a8   0x7fff30b035a8
rip            0x55ce8dc2460a   0x55ce8dc2460a <f>

--------------|--------------
ADDRESS       |VALUE
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035b0|               <= rbp
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a8|0x55ce8dc245fe <= rsp
--------------|--------------
```

3 push %rbp:

```
rax            0x0  0
rbp            0x7fff30b035b0   0x7fff30b035b0
rsp            0x7fff30b035a0   0x7fff30b035a0
rip            0x55ce8dc2460e   0x55ce8dc2460e <f+4>

--------------|--------------
ADDRESS       |VALUE
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035b0|               <= rbp
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a8|0x55ce8dc245fe
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a0|0x7fff30b035b0 <= rsp
--------------|--------------
```

4 mov %rsp, %rbp:

```
rax            0x0  0
rbp            0x7fff30b035a0   0x7fff30b035a0
rsp            0x7fff30b035a0   0x7fff30b035a0
rip            0x55ce8dc2460e   0x55ce8dc2460e <f+4>

--------------|--------------
ADDRESS       |VALUE
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035b0|
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a8|0x55ce8dc245fe
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a0|0x7fff30b035b0 <= rsp, rbp
--------------|--------------
```

5 mov $1, %eax:

```
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7fff30b035a0   0x7fff30b035a0
rsp            0x7fff30b035a0   0x7fff30b035a0
rip            0x55ce8dc24613   0x55ce8dc24613 <f+9>

--------------|--------------
ADDRESS       |VALUE
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035b0|
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a8|0x55ce8dc245fe
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a0|0x7fff30b035b0 <= rsp, rbp
--------------|--------------
```

6 leave: (mov %rbp %rsp, pop %rbp)

```
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7fff30b035b0   0x7fff30b035b0
rsp            0x7fff30b035a8   0x7fff30b035a8
rip            0x55ce8dc24614   0x55ce8dc24614 <f+10>

--------------|--------------
ADDRESS       |VALUE
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035b0|               <= rbp
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035a8|0x55ce8dc245fe <= rsp
--------------|--------------
```

7 ret:

```
rax            0x1  1
rbp            0x7fff30b035b0   0x7fff30b035b0
rsp            0x7fff30b035b0   0x7fff30b035b0
rip            0x55ce8dc24608   0x55ce8dc24608 <main+14>

--------------|--------------
ADDRESS       |VALUE
--------------|--------------
0x7fff30b035b0|               <= rbp, rsp
--------------|--------------
```